# Validate my database relationship?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Can someone please check and give any recommendations on the following database design. Please ignore the actual fields, I want more of a relationship check. Thank you :)

[image]

**Background**

A customer can have many  pet profiles say

1 Customer: has many pet profiles
pet profile has a 1 type (for example  Dog)

A dog has an has many attributes sets

Height
Weight

1 attributes set has many pet attribute answers e.g.

Weight = 1kg, 2kg, 3kg

---

Give this Scenario:

A customer add his/her pet. If a Dog for example (from pet type) a list of questions are asked for that pet type i.e. weight and height. From a drop down the they pick the best match. As I need to compare answers, so this CANNOT be free text.

**Update based on suggestions**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well looking it over it makes sense up to pet type, why not make that part of pet profile? isn't it same thing? and pet image? could be in pet profile any reason it's not? then use a surrogate key as a unique identifier, and I think that would correlate a little better to the pet attributes as everything is normalized and in one place - oppose to three separate tables....what do you think?

Essentially you are correlating a customer to one or many pets which is a combination of (petname, pettype, petpic, petattributes, add the lookups to the pet profile, and pet attributse so you can search by characteristics and by profile...

Same goes for reminder, add reminder type there? Why keep them separate? you are going to need a lot of joins when it's all said and done to retrieve information...and it's all at an individual level, so it's not like you're rolling anything up...yet

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, make alot of sense, but let me answer a few of your questions. pet type is the type of profile like Dog or Cat. the reason for this is the group of questions are different for a given pet type.

Comment: I do believe this can still be handled from a relational perspective, however this may be an exception, i think you can still do some of the things i mentioned above

Comment: So I have made an update based on suggestions, how does it look now? PS thanks for this really is helping :)

Comment: looks great bro, I think you will find this a much better solution! cheers my friend :)